# mailer doesn't launch in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios programming.

I'd like to launch a mailer when the specific cell is clicked.
So, I wrote this code today, but this code doesn't work.

What is wrong with my code?

```
if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 ) {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:email@test.com"];
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    //this condition fails and it outputs "Error" in console log.
    if([application canOpenURL:url]) {
        [application openURL:url];
    } else {

        NSLog(@"Error!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you testing in the simulator?

Comment: YES, I am. Is it the reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: Probably yes. There is no Mail on the simulator.

Comment: Thank you very much! I google about it and I found you are right!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no Mail app in the simulator, the `canOpenURL:`/`openURL:` functions will fail. Test these functionalities on a device.